# Cleaning up complex if statements for Chess game

Tags: javascript, chess

Shown below is a function I wrote for pawn move generation, I find it difficult to understand what the code does in a glance due to the cumbersome if statements, so any changes I make are done unnecessarily slowly. Is there a way to avoid these complex if statements so that the code is more maintainable?

```
  if(standardPawn.indexOf(this.board[position.y][position.x]) != -1){
          if(position.x + 1 < 8){
            if(board[position.y][position.x + 1].canEnpas === true && standardPawn.indexOf(board[position.y][position.x + 1]) == -1){
              moves.push({x: position.x + 1, y: position.y - 1});
            }
          }
          if(position.y == 6){
            if(board[position.y - 1][position.x] == "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x, y: position.y - 1});
            }
            if(board[position.y - 2][position.x] == "vacant" && board[position.y - 1][position.x] == "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x, y: position.y - 2});
            }
          } else if(position.y - 1 >= 0){
            if(board[position.y - 1][position.x] == "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x, y: position.y - 1});
            }
          }
          if(position.x + 1 < 8 && position.y - 1 >= 0){
            if(getPieceType({x: position.x + 1, y: position.y - 1}, this.board) != pieceType && board[position.y - 1][position.x + 1] != "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x + 1, y: position.y - 1});
            }
          }
          if(position.x - 1 >= 0 && position.y - 1 >= 0){
            if(getPieceType({x: position.x - 1, y: position.y - 1}, this.board) != pieceType && board[position.y - 1][position.x - 1] != "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x - 1, y: position.y - 1});
            }
          }
        } else {
          if(position.x + 1 < 8){
            if(board[position.y][position.x + 1].canEnpas === true && standardPawn.indexOf(board[position.y][position.x + 1]) != -1){
              moves.push({x: position.x + 1, y: position.y + 1});
            }
          }
          if(position.y == 1){
            if(board[position.y + 1][position.x] == "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x, y: position.y + 1});
            }
            if(board[position.y + 2][position.x] == "vacant" && board[position.y + 1][position.x] == "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x, y: position.y + 2});
            }
          } else if(position.y + 1 < 8){
            if(board[position.y + 1][position.x] == "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x, y: position.y + 1});
            }
          }
          if(position.x + 1 < 8 && position.y + 1 < 8){
            if(getPieceType({x: position.x + 1, y: position.y + 1}, this.board) != pieceType && board[position.y + 1][position.x + 1] != "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x + 1, y: position.y + 1});
            }
          }
          if(position.x - 1 >= 0 && position.y + 1 < 8){
            if(getPieceType({x: position.x - 1, y: position.y + 1}, this.board) != pieceType && board[position.y + 1][position.x - 1] != "vacant"){
              moves.push({x: position.x - 1, y: position.y + 1});
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can predefine some of the conditions.  E.g.

```
let blocked = (board[position.y - 1][position.x] !== "vacant")
let unmoved = (y === 6)
…
```

You can also define some short functions.  E.g. `isEnemy(x,y)` would return true if there is an enemy piece at that position.

Then using those variables in the tests will make them look tidier, and be easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can enhance the readability by extracting the conditons of your ifs to functions without chanceing the performance. Plus you can remove your duplicate code like positon.x +1 < 8